# MySQL Error Code: 1054. Unknown column 'fieldname' in 'field list'

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-workbench, collation, mysql-error-1054

I have a simple table with zero keys, and zero constraints of any kind, but I cannot select a column without copy and pasting the name from the table structure.

I have an image below that shows I ran two queries, and the column name is the same in both. The first attempt I typed the column name, the second attempt I copied the name from the table structure in the information panel below.

I have a feeling this may be a collation issue, but not the slightest clue how to fix it.

[image]

Comment: My guess is that you accidently used an invisible hidden character in the column name when creating the table.

Comment: I'd alter the name of column with exact string 'AuthorizationID' probably as @juergend mentioned there's invisible character that breaks the query because the names differ.

Comment: That seemed to work, all of the column names were created on a csv import initially, so there must have been some invisible character. Thanks for the help, I don't know why I didn't think to rename the field name.

Comment: Show us what you get from this; we'll help you decipher it: `select HEX(column_name) from information_schema.columns where table_name = 'lki_authorization'`

Answer (score 1):

The most likely cause for this are unseen characters in the column name.  You can access the column name using `information_schema`.  The most common reason would be trailing spaces, but if there were regular spaces, then neither version would work.

You can try this to get more information:

```
select concat('|', c.column_name, '|'), char_length(c.column_name)
from information_schema.columns c
where c.table_name = 'lki_authorization'
```

(Note:  You might also need `table_schema` to identify the table, but I'm guessing that is not necessary.)